# Dados sobrepondo no comando onClick

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Galera, to com um pequeno problema em *asp.net webforms*. E dei uma empacada legal.

Sei que a solução pra isso pode ser meio simples, mas estou confuso.

Segue o código:

```cs
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<Pessoa> lista; 

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!IsPostBack) return;

        if (lista == null)
            lista = new List<Pessoa>();
    }

    protected void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
        p.Id = lista.Count + 1;
        p.Nome = "João";
        p.Sobrenome = "Silva";
        p.Idade = 20;

        lista.Add(p);
        CarregarGrid();
    }

    private void CarregarGrid() {
        gvDados.DataSource = lista;
        gvDados.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Quando eu clico no botão, eu quero que seja adicionado uma nova pessoa na Grid, porem ele se sobrescreve, sempre no pageload da pagina a lista esta como 'null'.
Sempre ele adiciona:

**1 - joao - silva.**

Como consigo fazer isso mantendo as informações atuais? Sempre que clicar no botão quero que vá adicionando sempre mais um, como exemplo abaixo:

**1 - joao - silva.
2 - joao - silva.
3 - joao - silva....**

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a sua questão. Quando o GridView é carregado ele exibe os dados corretos, porém quando você clica em adicionar ele carrega todos os dados? Acho que para o seu caso talvez fosse melhor realizar uma iteração sobre a lista e adicionar um a um. Se o seu problema for com relação a perda de dados fornecidos pelo usuário.

Comment: @RichardDias Hum, certo, assim o problema é que na hora que eu clico no botão, a página da 'reload', e com isso perco as informações da lista. Ou seja, sempre vai ser um novo. Na primeira vez que eu clico, o GridView exibe o dado corretamente, mas ele SEMPRE exibe o primeiro dado.

Comment: Você já usou o modo debug para ver se a sua lista está sendo preenchida corretamente? Acho que para realizar esta ação talvez você pudesse usar ajax, evitaria recarregar a página toda. Não uso Web Forms, mas conheço um pouco de Windows Forms e MVC, então não sei realmente quais as implicações que isso pode trazer.

Comment: Certo, vou realizar o teste com ajax, acho que realmente o problema é no reload da página que ele perde as informações.Já usei o debug, e a lista é preenchida corretamente sim.

Comment: A não ser que ele armazene a lista em uma sessão. Ai tem que ver o que será melhor para o caso dele.

Comment: @TiagoSilva valeu pela dica do ViewState. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode resolver isso utilizando `ViewState[]`.

> ViewState é o mecanismo qual o ASP.NET utiliza para manter o estado de
>   controles e objetos quando um Postback ocorre na página. As
>   informações são armazenadas em um controle html do tipo hidden chamado
>   _VIEWSTATE.

[Fonte](https://www.codigofonte.net/dicas/dotnet/253_entendendo-o-que-e-viewstate)

**Faça da seguinte forma**

```cs
    public List<Pessoa> lista  { 
        get { return ViewState["Pessoas"] as List<Pessoa>; } 
        set{ lista = value; } 
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            ViewState["Pessoas"] = new List<Pessoa>();
            return;
        }
        if (lista == null) {
            lista = new List<Pessoa>();
        }
    }
    protected void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
        p.Id = lista.Count + 1;
        p.Nome = "João";
        p.Sobrenome = "Silva";
        p.Idade = 20;

        lista.Add(p);
        CarregarGrid();
    }
    private void CarregarGrid() {
        gvDados.DataSource = lista;
        gvDados.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: @FelipeOliveira, obrigado cara, funcionou perfeitamente, é exatamente esta funcionalidade que precisei. Valeu